# How to display series of images when app loads in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I want to display series of images one by one when the app loads. Basically I want to create some kind of animation by loading these images sequentially.

I know it is possible. I have seen many apps which does that.

Can you please let me know how can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UIImageView's animationImages property. You can assign an NSArray of images to this property. Below is an example but there may be typos as i'm typing this from memory.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UIImageView *flower = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
flower.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bloom1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bloom2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"bloom3.png"], nil]; //add more images as necessary

flower.animationDuration = 1.00;
flower.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[flower startAnimating];

[self.view addSubview:flower];

[flower release]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible,for displaying series of screen after the splash screen and before the first view of app appears .

for that Add below code to your AppDelegate.m file

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

```
// create the view that will execute our animation

[self.window addSubview:firstViewController.view];

{
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];

// load all the frames of our animation
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"],
                           nil];

imageView.animationDuration = 10.0;


// repeat the annimation once
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageView startAnimating];

// add the animation view to the main window 
[window insertSubview:imageView aboveSubview:firstViewController.view];
[imageView release];
```

}

```
[window setNeedsLayout];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 animationImageNumber=0;
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self                   
   selector:@selector(startAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
 }

 -(void)startAnimation
 {
   if (animationImageNumber<9) {
    animationImageNumber++;
   }
  else
   {
    animationImageNumber=0;
   }
   [self animationImageChange:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",animationImageNumber]];
  }

 -(void)animationImageChange:(NSString *)imageName
 { 
   NSString* imagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"jpg"];
   [backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
  }
```